# component-scan not working on jar file

Tags: java, spring, web-applications

springmvc-context.xml configuration file

1. [image: List item]

Jar is placed in WEB-INF/lib. 
Its giving 404 while trying to access the controller. How to find out its being initiating or not even and further work.

Comment: <context:annotation-config/>
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nucleus.finnone.tbs.service.rest.*" />
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.nucleus.lms.web.reportmanager.*" />

Answer (score 0):

Try to place:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

this dependency in pom.xml file for the spring-context jars.

But before this have you placed your jar file from WEB-INF/lib to the build path. If not the first place the jar in the build path of the project.

This might help. Thanks!!!

Comment: spring-context-support-4.1.6.RELEASE jar is there in classpath. Our project doesnt contain pom.

Comment: It was <context:component-scan base-package="com.nucleus.finnone" /> of application-context.xml that was limiting it to scan. Its above servlet-context.xml in hierarchy. Changing it to <context:component-scan base-package="com.nucleus" /> WORKING FINE.